# simultaneous audio output from two external sound cards connected to a usb hub

Tags: python, pulseaudio

How do I go about playing 2 different mp3 files from two different USB sound cards?
The mp3 files are stored locally and I would like to use python script to choose a file and play it on one of the two sound cards?

I found through some browsing over the internet about pulseaudio.
If I install pulseaudio and create two sinks ,one USB sound card each, will I be able to select a sink and play a file choosing a sink from python?
What package/library would I need in python to interface with pulseaudio sinks?

Thanks!

Comment: is this possible with pymad and pyaudio together?

Comment: How do I select soundcard in pyaudio

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a python library that simply may execute terminal commands and then use **[pactl](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pactl)** to upload an audio sample via `pactl upload-sample FILENAME [NAME]` and playback via `pactl play-sample ID SINK`.

Be sure the python process is run by a user that can control pulseaudio, and is part of the groups `audio`, `pulse`, and `pulse-rt`